# SQL for selecting rows in DB

Tags: php, mysql

On my website I have a page where users can answer one question at a time.
The questions that are provided are stored in the questions table. 
When the user answers a question it gets stored in the answers table. 
After answering a question it moves on to the next question.

**The way my code works** right now is it selects a question from the questions table and then joins the answers table `WHERE answers.id IS NULL`. (the user hasn't answered this question.)

**The way I need it to work** is similar to above, except it needs to also check if the question has been answered by the user, and if it has don't display it and move on to the next question the user hasn't answered.

I hope I've explained myself well enough.

**The code I'm currently using**

```
$db = db_open();
$query = "SELECT 
          questions.id, 
          questions.question
          FROM questions 
          LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.id = answers.question 
          WHERE answers.id IS NULL 
          GROUP BY questions.id";
$result = db_query($db,$query);
$result = db_fetch_array($result);
$default_question = array("id"=>$result["id"],"question"=>$result["question"]);
```

**Question table**

```
id  question
1   This is a question
```

**Answer table**

```
id   user   question   answer
 1    1      1         This is an answer
```

Comment: your `answers.id` is primary key i guess.correct?

Comment: I'm sorry I still find it a little confusing on what you want. Are you talking about displaying if a specific user has not answered the question?

Comment: Let's say two users are answering questions. They both get the same questions. If user one answers first, he gets the next question, and user two is still on the first question. It needs to work like that. I think that's an easier way of explaining it.

Comment: So all user has to answer all the questions?

Comment: It just needs to check if the user has answered question one, if not display it for that user. If he has, then check if he's answered question two, if not, display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$user_id = getUserIdOrSomethingLikeThat(); 
$query = "SELECT 
      questions.id, 
      questions.question
      FROM questions 
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT * FROM answers WHERE answers.question = questions.id AND answers.user = $user_id 
      )
```

Also consider to refactor your table definitions. A the column names are confusing. Something like this would be better:

question table fields: id, body

answer table fields: id, question_id, user_id,body

Comment: I've tried this. It's a double negative. If answers.id is NULL, then why would there be a user id?

Comment: Edited my 1st answer.

Comment: My column names are actually dumbed down a little to make this easier. Apparently it didn't lol.